# getComponent doesn't render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, single-page-application

I try to set up [dynamic routing](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#9-async-loading) with react-router and webpack. `require.ensure` function loads module, but [getComponent](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback) method doesn't render component.

In my example `Button` component is rendered by default (on home page). When I click on the button, router redirects me to /admin url and I can see in my web console that `require.ensure` loaded new chunk, but `Label` component is not rendered.

**index.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, useRouterHistory, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
import Button from './components/button';

let appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({queryKey: false});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={appHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>

    <Route path="/" component={Button} >
        <Route path="index" getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
          require.ensure([], function (require) {
              cb(null, require('./components/button').default)
            })}}
        />
        <Route path="admin" getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
          require.ensure([], function (require) {
              cb(null, require('./components/label').default)
            })}}
        />
    </Route>

    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**button.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var bootstrapStyle = require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css");

export default class Button extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onRedirect = this.onRedirect.bind(this);
    }

  onRedirect(){
    this.context.router.push({
                pathname: `/admin`
            });
  }

  render() {
    return <button className="btn btn-info" type="button" onClick={this.onRedirect}>
      <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
    </button>;
  }
}

Button.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

**label.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var bootstrapStyle = require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css");

export default class Label extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span className="label label-default">Default</span>;
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "history": "^2.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.4",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.15.0"
  }
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but in this code `pathname: \`/admin\`` are those quotes correct?

Comment: @pablopunk backticks are valid string delimiters in ES6 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Can you show us webpack config? Did webpack produce 3 chunks for you? How do you include main `.js` file in html?

Comment: @Everettss yes, webpack produces separated chunks. I had wrong router configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue isn't `getComponent` or dynamic routing but your route configuration. When navigating to `/admin`, react-router matches your top-level and admin routes and renders accordingly: `<Button><Label /></Button>`. Since `Button` doesn't render `this.props.children`, `Label` won't be rendered either.

By looking at your code, maybe this is the config you wanted:

```
<Route path="/" component={props => <div>{props.children}</div>}>
   <IndexRoute component={Button} />
   <Route path="index" />
   <Route path="admin" />
</Route>
```

You can read more about how components are rendered in the [route configuration guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md) and the [Route API](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#component).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't import your component on the fly like `require('./components/label').default`. You have to import your component:

```
import Label from './components/label';
```

then to code:

```
cb(null, Label);
```

[source](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback)

Comment: I tried it, but Label component is not loaded. I am trying to implement [dynamic routing](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#9-async-loading)

Comment: @Matt code looks valid. This dynamic require is common in chunking app by webpack. Have a look on this code: https://github.com/Everettss/spa-optimization/blob/stage1/src/routes.js

Comment: @Everettss thanks for sharing, I will try it out :) In my case I had wrong router configuration